# How to redirect console to ttyprintk

Tags: linux-kernel, tty

all.
I am trying to implement the phrase written in the ttyprintk description:
`The feature is useful to inline user messages with kernel messages. In order to use this feature, you should output user messages to /dev/ttyprintk or redirect console to this TTY, or boot the kernel with console=ttyprintk.`

1. I tried command line setting console=ttyprintk. Kernel comeup looks ok till it comes to the serial driver initialization. From this point it becomes garbage (as if baudrate has changed) till the Arago logo and kernel prompt, when everything normalizes by itself, but console messages are not printk'ed (no time prefix appears).
2. I don't understand how can i redirect console to ttyprintk, The chvt command takes only numbers.
3. Somewhere in the internet I saw people speaking about symlinking ttyprintk to console, but I wasn't able to find what to link to what. And how to do this when all these are real nodes in /dev directory.

Thanks for any hint/help.

Comment: **Warning regarding 3**. I can't tell if that would work however cat-ing to /dev/ttyprintk would certainly be more appropriate than cp-ing whatever, command which is likely to have replaced your special file with an ordinary file holding the same content that some.text

Comment: Wow, @MC68020, how did I miss this?! Inertia... THANK YOU!!!! You are right and cat-ing works!    So, remains a small move - how do I redirect console to this /dev/ttyprintk!!!??? And my task will be solved!